# Prove the inequality$|x|-|y|≤|x+y|$

Tags: calculus

The question tells me that i can use $x=(x+y)-y$  and $|x+y|≤|x|+|y|$ to prove. But i don't know where to use  $x=(x+y)-y$.

Till now,i only get that $-|x|-|y|≤|x+y|$ from the use of $|x|≤A$,$-A≤x≤A$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \lvert x \rvert = \lvert (x+y)-y \rvert \\
\leq \lvert x+y \rvert + \lvert -y \rvert = \lvert x+y \rvert + \lvert y \rvert,. $$
the first equality being the first part of the hint, the second being the inequality in the hint, albeit with symbols with different names (write $z=x+y$, $w=-y$, then one has $\lvert z+w \rvert \leq \lvert z \rvert + \lvert w \rvert$ using the hint: it doesn't just mean the original $x$ and $y$, but any numbers).

Comment: Good to see that you're still alive.  (+1) for the answer.  Remember to good ole days when the site had a plethora of cool analysis questions (neat series, products, integrals, and beyond)?  What the heck happened?

Comment: Thanks.I have sloved my problem.

Comment: @MarkViola IK,R? Been quite a disappointing last few months on here. Let's hope things improve once the academic year gets properly going.

Comment: @Chappers Just curious ... What did you mean by "IK, R?"

Comment: @MarkViola "I know, right?"

Comment: Ah, ISN.  How did I miss that?